# Random numbers, Symbols, Characters, in a stream C/C++

Tags: c++, random, struct, filestream

Hi guys I'm new here and a little new in c/c++, I dont usually practise streams but when I tried to make one, opening my file created with this code I always get random numbers, chars, symbols and trash in the .txt file created. 
Like this: 
[Hellothere.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Eg8.png). I see random symbols, character instead of numbers entered, the name is OK because it shows well, but sometimes when I write long names it will write trash.

Can you help me to solve this?, Here's the code:

---

```
    struct sample {
       int code; 
       char name [20]; 
    } sampl;

    int main () {
        cout<<" ENTER CODE : "<<endl;
        cin>>sampl.code;

        cout<<" ENTER NAME :"<<endl;
        gets(sampl.name);

        fflush(stdin);

      FILE *fp;
      fp=fopen("Hellothere.txt", "rb+");

      if(fp==NULL) {

          fp=fopen("Hellothere.txt","wb+");
          if(fp==NULL) {
                puts("CANNOT OPEN");
                return 0;
          }
      }

        fwrite(&sampl,sizeof(sampl),1,fp);
        fclose(fp);

        getchar();
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated, `fflush(stdin);` - don't do that. It isn't standard in any way. And `gets(sampl.name);` - don't do that *ever*, `gets` is so hideous it has been removed from the standard library for its heinousness. All that said, understand you're writing the *entire* content of a `sample` object to your file, including the bytes in `name` that you didn't set, and the implementation representation of an `int` in memory. Your code doesn't perform *formatted output*, so what you get out of it is exactly what you told it to do; dump the memory representation of a `sample` to a disk file.

Comment: I read your answer many times but I didn't get it at 100%, but yeah I understoo you, but how would I solve this?, Should I changue the `int code` to `char code` , right? correct me.

Comment: Or you can edit my code or tell me what should I write there to solve it, or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing C++ and older C facilities for input and output. You'll have a much easier time if you stick to just C++.

First, let's replace your struct with the C++ equivalent:

```
struct sample {
    int code;
    std::string name;
};
```

Now `name` can hold as many characters as necessary.

We'll now write a function which will output a `sample` to a C++ output stream:

```
std::ostream& write_sample(std::ostream& os, const sample& samp)
{
    os << samp.code << "\n" << samp.name; 
    return os;
}
```

This will output the code followed by the name, with a newline in between them.

Now let's modify your `main()` routine to use C++ facilities to fill the struct:

```
int main()
{
    sample samp;

    cout << "ENTER CODE :\n";
    cin >> samp.code;

    cost << "ENTER NAME :\n";
    cin >> samp.name;
}
```

Now, we can quickly check whether we've got things right by using our `write_sample()` function with `std::cout`, which is a type of output stream:

```
write_sample(std::cout, samp);
```

This should repeat what you entered out to the console.

To write to a file instead, we can use C++ facilities to open a file stream:

```
std::ofstream outfile{"Hellothere.txt"};
```

Now, we can again use our `write_sample()` function with this new stream:

```
write_sample(outfile, samp);
```

And when your program runs, Hellothere.txt should contain the text you entered.

As a final (slightly more advanced) touch, you might want to rename your `write_sample()` function to `operator<<`, which will allow you to use the standard `<<` streaming style:

```
outfile << samp;
```

Put it all together and the final code should look like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct sample {
    int code;
    std::string name;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const sample& samp)
{
    return os << samp.code << "\n" << samp.name;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    sample samp;

    cout << "Enter code:\n";
    cin >> samp.code;

    cout << "Enter name:\n";
    cin >> samp.name;

    std::ofstream outfile{"Hellothere.txt"};
    outfile << samp;
}
```

Comment: I read your answer 3 times and now I understand it perfectly, thank you for the help <3 , Now im loving this page because its helpful. Thanks mate.